# How to create logic to lookup for custom case number on case object?

Tags: case, formula-field, lookup

I have a Visualforce page which is used to create customer service related cases on the case object. We have a custom case number value for each case created (`QR-1001`, `QR-1002` .....).

For certain new cases, we have to add a previous closed case as a reference which had the same issue as the new case. We have a lookup field to Case object where we enter the standard case number instead of the custom case number (`QR-1001`).

Is there any way that I can create a formula field which populates the custom case number of the reference case? If so, How do I do it?

This is my lookup field to case: `QR_Reference_QR__c` (Data type: Lookup)

Child relationship name: `AssociatedQRCases`

This is the custom case number field: `QR_Case_Number__c` (Data type: Auto number).

Can any one help how do I write a formula field which shows the custom case number of the look up case record based on the standard case number?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make the wording more clear? I have no idea what you mean by "not possible to look up for custom fields on Case". It might help if you go into more detail about what objects are involved here instead of just listing the fields that you have.

Comment: Are you looking for information on [cross-object formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Yes. All I want do is create a custom field which populates the custom case number of the reference case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a typical [cross-object formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=5). Based on your description, the following should work:

```
QR_Reference_QR__r.QR_Case_Number__c
```

There's nothing different about the approach based on using a custom Auto Number field on the parent Case. You can display it on the child the same way you'd display any other field on an object connected by a lookup relationship.

Comment: Great. Thank you!